# save file from unit test to project tree

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, junit

In the unit tests as a side effect I am creating screenshots for various parts of the GUI.
I want to use these screenshots when compiling the documentation.

Therefore I want to save them to a directory within the source tree.

Is there any reliable way to get the source directory root when running a junit test?

If not, how can I make sure that unit tests run with cwd=project root when using eclipse, and when using maven?

Answer (score 1):

wether you execute tests on eclipse or using maven, if you don't specify a path when you create the file it's automatically created at project root directory.

so if you specify a relative folder your files will go there :

```
public class TestFileCreation {

@Test
public void testFileCreation() throws IOException {
    File f = new File("src/main/resources/hello.txt");
    OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);
    String data = "Hello there !";
    ostream.write(data.getBytes());
    ostream.close();
}
```

}

will create a file inside the $PROJECT/src/main/resources.

Hope my answer helps

Comment: Thanks, I have taken this direction. I am checking for the existence of the directory to make sure I am in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can base on your classes location. Proposed solution here is to use class that will surely be in classpath. Then you can use `class.getResource("")`. Example

```
public class ResouceRoot {

    public static String get() {
        String s = ResouceRoot.class.getResource("").toString();
        if (s.startsWith("jar:")) {
            s = s.replace("jar:", "").replaceAll("!.*", "");
        } else {
            s = s.replaceAll("classes.*", "classes");
        }
        File f = new File(s.replace("file:", ""));
        return f.getParentFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(get());
    }
}
```

(this code will give base dir for netbeans projects if they are launched from netbeans or by `java -jar ...` )